# Chrome Commands API to make default popup visible

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was looking at the [`chrome.commands`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) API for adding some functionality to m y extension.

Basically what I want to do is to listen for specific key combinations, say <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, to display the default popup of my extension.

I understood how that could be included in the manifest. Reading further, I found this:

> In your background page, you can bind a handler to each of the
>   commands defined in the manifest (except for '_execute_browser_action'
>   and '_execute_page_action') via onCommand.addListener.

What I understand is that I need to have a background page that listens for these key combinations and takes actions appropriately. All good.

and there is this paragraph, too:

> The '_execute_browser_action' and '_execute_page_action' commands are
>   reserved for the action of opening your extension's popups. They won't
>   normally generate events that you can handle. If you need to take
>   action based on your popup opening, consider listening for an
>   'onDomReady' event inside your popup's code.

The difficulty that remains is :
**How do I make the default popup visible?**  :)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, that remark says "you don't need to (and can't) handle these actions yourself".
They will open the popup regardless, and listeners don't get fired.

So, for a minimal example a background page is not needed at all.

In the manifest:

```
"commands": {
  "_execute_browser_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Alt+S",
    }
  }
}
```

And then Ctrl+Alt+S will mimic clicking your browser action.

- If a popup is set, it will open it.
- If not, `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` will fire.
- The `chrome.commands.onCommand` even will not fire in either case.